# NDSolve coupled differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve these ADE,
Constants are

```
\[Beta]0 = 10^-7;
\[Theta]0 = 30
```

``
Density and pressure is given by;

```
`d[r_] := 4*Pi*



NIntegrate[(1 + x)^2 (Sqrt[(1 + x)^2 - 1])/(1 + 
       Exp[x/\[Beta][r]]*Exp[-\[Theta][r]]), {x, 0, 100}]

p[r_] := 4*Pi/3*
  NIntegrate[(1 + 
      x/2) (Sqrt[(1 + x)^2 - 1])/(1 + 
       Exp[x/\[Beta][r]]*Exp[-\[Theta][r]]), {x, 0, 100}]
```

`

temperature perameter give is one extra Algebraic expression
[Beta][r_] = [Beta]0*Exp[[Nu][r]/2]

Equilibrium differential Equations are, with boundary conditions

```
`sol = NDSolve[{\[Theta]'[
     r] == (-1 - \[Beta][
        r] (\[Theta][r] - \[Theta]0) (M[r] + 4 Pi*p[r]*r^3)/\[Beta][
         r]*(r^2 - 2*M[r]*r)),M'[r] == 4*Pi*r^2*d[r], \[Nu]'[r] == 
    2 (M[r] + 4*p[r]*r^3)/\[Beta][0]*(r^2 - 2 M[r]*r), \[Theta][0] == 
    10, M[0] == 0, \[Nu][0] == 0}, {\[Theta], M, \[Nu]}, {r, 10^-4, 
   10^6}]  `
```

`\theta, M, \nu` are dependant variables of differential equation, depending on r.

Comment: Getting an error "NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ((1+x/2) Sqrt[-1+(1+x)^2])/(1+E^(10000000 E^Times[<<2>>]  x-\[Theta][r])) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}."

Comment: You need to check if any of the symbols you have used is not assigned to a numerical value before you use NIntegrate

Comment: So, what's the question here? Please show us the complete code sample that reproduces your problem.